# Encrypted Classloader

Tags: java, encryption, arrays, classloader

I created myself a framework with "reverse-RSA" (Encryption with PrivateKey) in java and wanted to expand this to loading classes at runtime. I know that this is no efficient protection against theft of my code but my goal is to prevent (with best effort) people to alter my code.

For the past few hours I have searched for a method to load classes at runtime (and found some answers here, but none of them helped me), given only a byteArray containing the decrypted JarFile. I am working with a custom Classloader which is supposed to load the .class file which you can see below:

```
public class MemoryClassLoader extends ClassLoader{
private byte[] current = null;

public MemoryClassLoader(){
    super(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
}

@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class res = null;
    try {
        res = defineClass(name, current,0,current.length,null);
    }catch(SecurityException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not load the Class with our custom method(" + e.getMessage() + ")  Falling back to the super method.");
        res = super.loadClass(name,true);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("An error occured while loading the class: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return res;
}

@Override
public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return findClass(name);
}

public final void setContents(final byte[] data){
    current = new byte[data.length];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, current, 0, data.length);
}
```

I am feeding the loader like this:

```
    public final void loadClasses(final File jarFile) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException{
    JarInputStream in = new JarInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(decrypt(jarFile)));//Block-like decryption 
    JarEntry je;
    MemoryClassLoader loader = new MemoryClassLoader();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[251658240];//30 MB
    while((je=in.getNextJarEntry())!=null){
        if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class"))continue;
        in.read(buffer);
        buffer = trim(buffer);//Trim off all 0's at the end
        loader.setContents(buffer);
        Class c = loader.loadClass(je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6).replace("/", "."));//Try to load the class
    }
    in.close();
}
```

The decryption and the rest works just fine, but the class loader prints

> Could not load the Class with our custom method(Prohibited package name: java.lang)  Falling back to the super method.

into the console, then uses the superordinate loadClass which surprisingly works (since the original file remains encrypted). 
This works thought but my question is, why does this error occur and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your current class loader is trying to load Java SDK classes as well. That's why you get that error. Try checking the package names in `findClass()` and use the *System Class Loader* to load the ones that are not in your packages.

Comment: As simple as that, maybe I worked too long. I am checking if the name starts with java and then use the Systems classloader. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, btw a white-listing approach might be better.

Comment: That would definitely be the best way, but it would result in the same I guess.